# How do I confirm if a radio button is selected if the button has 2 xpaths?

Tags: python, selenium

I am trying to create an if/else statement using Selenium in Python, where if the radio button is not already selected, it should be clicked. Otherwise, it should print that the button is already selected.

The below syntax doesn't return errors, but it still clicks the button every time, regardless of if it is already selected or not.

```
selectallfive = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//a[contains(text(),"Select All")]')
if selectallfive.is_selected():
    print('already selected')
else:
    selectallfive.click()
```

Upon inspecting the element of the button, I realized that the button has 2 xpaths --- one for when the button is already clicked `//a[@class='checked']` and one for when the button is not checked `//a[contains(text(),'Select All')]`. I suspect that I may need to transform the xpath used in my if/else statement, but I am not sure how to go about this in Selenium Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fetch the list of the element by fetching it by its clicked state xpath. If the size of list is greater than 0, it means the element is present and checkbox is clicked and if the size is equal to zero, it means the element is not present and then you need click on the element by fetching it by its not clicked state xpath.

You can do it like:

```
# Fetching the list of element with checkbox clicked xpath
clicked_element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//a[@class='checked']")

# Checking if its present or not
if len(clicked_element) == 0:
    # Checkbox is not clicked, so click on the element
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Select All')]").click()
else:
    # Element is already selected
    print('already selected')
```